# How to dynamically return Object attributes in python, including attributes of objects that are attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a testing program for a python program that takes data, does calculations on it, then puts the output in a class instance object. This object contains several other objects, each with their own attributes. I'm trying to access all the attributes and sub-attributes dynamically with a one size fits all solution, corresponding to elements in a dictionary I wrote to cycle through and get all those attributes for printing onto a test output file.

Edit: this may not be clear from the above but I have a list of the attributes I want, so using something to actually get those attributes is not a problem, although I'm aware python has methods that accomplish this. What I need to do is to be able to get all of those attributes with the same function call, regardless of whether they are top level object attributes or attributes of object attributes.

Python is having some trouble with this - first I tried doing something like this:

```
for string in attr_dictionary:
    ...
    outputFile.print(outputclass.string)
    ...
```

But Python did not like this, and returned an `AttributeError`

After checking SE, I learned that this is a supposed solution:

```
for string in attr_dictionary:
    ...
    outputFile.print(getattr(outputclass, string))
    ...
```

The only problem is - I want to dynamically access the attributes of objects that are attributes of `outputclass`. So ideally it would be something like `outputclass.objectAttribute.attribute`, but this does not work in python. When I use `getattr(outputclass, objectAttribute.string)`, python returns an `AttributeError`

Any good solution here?

One thing I have thought of trying is creating methods to return those sub-attributes, something like:

```
class outputObject:
    ...
    def attributeIWant(self,...):
        return self.subObject.attributeIWant
    ...
```

Even then, it seems like getattr() will return an error because attributeIWant() is supposed to be a function call, it's not actually an attribute. I'm not certain that this is even within the capabilities of Python to make this happen.

Thank you in advance for reading and/or responding, if anyone is familiar with a way to do this it would save me a bunch of refactoring or additional code.

edit: Additional Clarification

The class for example is `outputData`, and inside that class you could have and instance of the class `furtherData`, which has the attribute `dataIWant`:

```
class outputData:
    example: furtherData
    example = furtherData()
    example.dataIWant = someData
...
```

with the python getattr I can't access both attributes directly in `outputData` and attributes of `example` unless I use separate calls, the attribute of example needs two calls to getattr.

Edit2: I have found a solution I think works for this, see below

Comment: Each "level" of attribute needs its own `getattr` call.  That is: call `getattr` to get the `objectAttribute` of `outputclass`, and then call `getattr` on *that* to get its `attribute`.

Comment: ah, much appreciated - but that still means there's no one size fits all approach to this issue then?

Comment: @Brandon can you provide a minimal example the data, the calculations and the attributes you are trying to access?

Comment: @alexpdev These wouldn't be relevant to the question - the data and calculations are dealt with outside of the logic for printing all of this to a file. At this stage in the app it's simply accessing object attributes and printing them into a file.

Comment: @brandon Yes but providing a simple example would help me understand what you are trying to achieve. maybe a better way to ask is, can you provide an example of the instance class that you are trying to print the attributes of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community   I'm not exactly sure what's not clear but I'll try to add some additional clarification inside the question

Comment: hey @alexpdev I added a little bit of clarification above, I hope that can help a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out - I just wrote a quick function that splits the attribute string (for example `outputObj.subObj.propertyIWant`) then proceeds down the resultant array, calling `getattr` on each subobject until it reaches the end of the array and returns the actual attribute.

Code:

```
def obtainAttribute(sample, attributeString: str):
    baseObj = sample
    attrArray = attributeString.split(".")
    for string in attrArray:
        if(attrArray.index(string) == (len(attrArray) - 1)):
            return getattr(baseObj,string)
        else:
            baseObj = getattr(baseObj,string)
    return "failed"
```

`sample` is the object and `attributeString` is, for example `object.subObject.attributeYouWant`

Comment: I am still confused about what you are trying to achieve because I can't run this code to see what it does, but I am glad you were able to figure it out.  Sometimes it can be difficult to convey an idea that you think has been explained as well as can be already because as the source of the idea you already understand it.  I have been in this situation too.  This is why it's good to provide a minimal working example so others can run the code and watch it from start to end and see exactly what you mean.  :)

Comment: @alexpdev ah, that's my bad sorry, I'll make sure to do that next time. Thanks for your help and patience with this :)